# WEB service C# - Cannot start service from the command line or debugger

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I am getting the below error **(on debugging)**:

> Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A Windows
> Service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then
> started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool
> or the NET START command.

I running the program in Visual Studio as Administrator.

```
class Program : ServiceBase
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run(new Program());
        }

        public Program()
        {
#if DEBUG
            OnStart(null);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
#endif
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        { 
                BO_Demo_Service.Utils.Helper.Run();
        }
 protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }
}
```

Comment: What Project template have you been using to create the project? For a Web Service you should use one of the WebService templates. It will give you all the settings to start it in a debug session.

Comment: ... and mind you "**Web** Service" != "**Windows** Service"

Comment: Hi @Fildor ,the the main project template is consoleApp that I change (class Program : ServiceBase) and it runs a web service project.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You'd have to make substantial changes to the project to turn it into a _windows_ service, which is _not equal_ to a _web_ service in the first place. So, the question is: What do you actually want? A windows service or a web service? You _can_ host a web service inside a windows service but that would be rather unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Windows service is a little bit different from other types - you cannot start it direcly via visual studio - it has to be published/compiled and installed as windows service. Essentially windows service project mostly looks like this :

```
 public class YourService : ServiceBase
    {
        ServiceHost sHost;

        public YourService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceYouAreHosting));
            sHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            sHost.Close();
        }
    }
```

All the processing is mostly done in [ServiceYouAreHosting], and this service only has methods/actions that can be controlled via "net start (or stop)" command (alternatively run "services.msc" via run command).

If you still want to test service via visual studio - create new project (e.g. console application) in your solution and try

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost sHost;
            sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceYouAreHosting));
            sHost.Open();

            while (true) { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: " create new project... and try..." Or use the `#if DEBUG` directive in your project